# SQL Server 2005 View get the calling SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I have a view, now I need in my view the SQL Statement that is selecting me.
For example:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM myView WHERE col1 LIKE 'test%'
```

Now in my view I need my calling SQL Statement to send it with an CLR Function to a web service.
Is it possible to get this SQL Statement that SELECTS the view inside the view?

I tried it with

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exex_sql_text(sqlhandle) AS sqltext
```

but it gives me all statements that currently running, so I get when I do 3 SELECTS I get all of them in my result.

Or gives me the statement I tried all statements that are executed in this connection?

Comment: Does that query not work?

Comment: Use SQL Server Profiler to see exactly what's happening in your SQL Server database

Comment: I clarify it a bit more

Comment: Why not to use table valued function or stored proc instead?

Comment: because its needed to redirect the statements from an old application that is not changeable, so we only see the chance to catch their statements and redirect them